# Polars: Search and replace in column names

Tags: python-polars

This used to be handled in `pandas` as so:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.','_')
```

This code works but definitely doesn't feel like the correct solution.

```
renamed = {}
for column_name in list(filter(lambda x: '.' in  x, df.columns)):
    renamed[column_name] = column_name.replace('.', '_')
df = df.rename(renamed)
```

Thx

Comment: Very nice, thank you.  I too wish there was something more straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.columns` returns a python `List[str]` and it also supports `__setitem__`, so you can just use python here.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a.c": [1, 2],
    "b.d": [3, 4]
})
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(".", "_"), df.columns))
print(df)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a_c ┆ b_d │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [polars.Expr.map_alias](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_alias.html), which applies a given function to each column name. It is particularly useful for renaming columns in method chaining.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col.a': [1, 2],
    'col.b': [3, 2]
})

res = df.select(
    pl.all().map_alias(lambda col_name: col_name.replace('.', '_'))
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ col_a ┆ col_b │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 3     │
│ 2     ┆ 2     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

As of polars 0.19.12, map_alias is deprecated and replaced by [.name.map](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.map.html#polars.Expr.name.map).

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a.c": [1, 2],
    "b.d": [3, 4]
})
df = df.select(
    pl.all().name.map(lambda col_name: col_name.replace('.', '_'))
)
print(df)
```

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a_c ┆ b_d │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to a pandas df, there is a rename method in polars which replaces column name with a dictionary mapper.

```
df = df.rename({"old_name": "new_name})
```

[polars docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rename.html#polars.DataFrame.rename)

Comment: This partially answers the question. The ask is to search for a particular character and replace it with another character. Please edit your answer and add the missing part.

Answer (score 1):

[`pl.DataFrame.rename`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rename.html) accepts a callable mapping as parameter. In your example, it can be used as follows.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo.total": [1],
    "bar.min": [2],
    "bar.max": [3],
})

df.rename(lambda name: name.replace(".", "_"))
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ foo_total ┆ bar_min ┆ bar_max │
│ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1         ┆ 2       ┆ 3       │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```