# Polars: Search and replace in column names: is it possible with LazyFrames?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, python-polars

A follow up from an already answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351393/polars-search-and-replace-in-column-names), is it possible to Search and replace column names in a LazyFrame? I am doing this as a workaround (based on the linked answer by ritchie46, and thanks for that!):

```
df = df.lazy().collect()
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.replace("Total", ""), df.columns))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
(pl.DataFrame({
    "Total_foo": [1],
    "bar_Total": [2],
    "other": [3],
}).lazy()
  .select(
     pl.all().map_alias(lambda name: name.replace("Total", ""))
 )).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ _foo ┆ bar_ ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3     │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! Amazing library, loving it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [`pl.LazyFrame.rename`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.rename.html).

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.LazyFrame({
    "Total_foo": [1],
    "bar_Total": [2],
    "other": [3],
})

df.rename(lambda name: name.replace("Total", "")).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ _foo ┆ bar_ ┆ other │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3     │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```